# What does prob function do in driver? how to write isr in driver?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver

Sorry to ask some basic questions but I am not clear about basic driver implementation. I referred the below source code to understand:
[minimal driver](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/07/05/devhelloworld-a-simple-introduction-to-device-drivers-under-linux.html?page=2)

As far as I know in a driver I should have module_init & module_exit function. module init will perform the registration of the driver. Driver should contain the read & write function depending on requirement. proc file system and any other file system is used to communicate between user space and kernel space.

Please correct me if I am wrong. 
I want to implement serial driver. Does __init will register the driver? How to write irq (interrupt) in a driver? what are the steps required to write driver?

I referred the below code for serial driver:
[uart driver](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/serial/uartlite.c)

Comment: I suggest to refer sample char driver code. https://github.com/jeyaramvrp/kernel-module-programming/tree/master/sample-char-dir

Comment: The best reference for learning the details of writing Linux device drivers is the excellent book by McKellar, Rubini, Corbet and Kroah-Hartman, "Linux Device Drivers" 4th edition. Most if not all of your questions will be answered in this excellent text. Have fun!